# SIGSEV when trying to access dynamic array of pointers (C)

Tags: c

I get an error when the scanf tries to access titolo[i]->nome and I don't get why

```
typedef struct tit *TITOLO;

struct tit {
    char nome[20];
};

int main()
{
    TITOLO *titolo;
    titolo =(TITOLO *) malloc(4*sizeof (TITOLO));
    if (titolo == NULL) exit(1);
    int i;
    for (i=0;i<4;i++) {
        printf("Insert title: ");
        scanf("%s", titolo[i]->nome);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: That's the reason people are saying not to conceal pointers with `typedef`.

Comment: I ran your code. I didn't get the error. What is the error you are getting ?

Comment: @Syed.Waris I get segmentation fault at the scanf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want this:

```
typedef struct tit *TITOLO;

struct tit {
  char nome[20];
};

int main()
{
  TITOLO titolo;
  titolo = (TITOLO)malloc(4 * sizeof(struct tit));
  if (titolo == NULL) exit(1);
  int i;
  for (i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    printf("Insert title: ");
    scanf("%s", titolo[i].nome);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

`TITOLO` is already pointer type.

**But best is to do as suggested by Lundin's answer and the multiply upvoted comment: don't hide pointers types behind typedefs, it only adds confusion.**

BTW:

```
... = (TITOLO)malloc(...
```

can be written as:

```
... = malloc(...
```

the cast is not necessary at all.

Answer (score 6):

`typedef struct tit *TITOLO;` defines TITOLO as a pointer type, not a struct type. Get rid of this and typedef the struct instead:

```
typedef struct {
    char nome[20];
} TITOLO;

TITOLO* titolo = malloc(4*sizeof(*titolo));
```

Comment: Isn't there any way to do like I wanted? I just made a simpler example of a much bigger exercise, unfortunately I can't get rid of it